# How to Pinjoint2D darts(Kinematicbody2D) on moving wall(StaticBody2D) via gdscript

Tags: godot

I have a shooting darts (KinematicBody2D) that will need to stick on a moving wall (staticbody2D).
I wants to let the dart stick on the wall, and change position according to how the wall move (currently my wall is moved by updating its position).

However, the dart does not follow fully the moving path of the wall.

I end up adding pinJoint2D, but setting the node via gdscript only give me an error

```
Invalid set index 'node_b' (on base: 'PinJoint2D') with value of type 'StaticBody2D (StaticBody2DWall.gd)'.
```

My code in dart node for setting up pinjoint2d goes as below:

```
var slide_count = get_slide_count()
if slide_count:
    var collision = get_slide_collision(slide_count - 1)
    var collider = collision.collider
    lif collider.is_in_group("wall"):
        $PinJoint2D.node_b = collider
```

Anyone please help. Please let me know if there's a better practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node_b member is a node path, not a node. Try the following:

```
$PinJoint2D.node_b = collider.get_path()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But the dart is still not following the movable wall as expected. The game does not crash but throw an error saying `affine_invert: Condition "det == 0" is true.  <C++ Source>  core/math/transform_2d.cpp:51 @ affine_invert()`.  Do you have any clue how to fix it?

Comment: @Pengyou Not really. That looks like a separate and maybe unrelated problem. I suggest asking a new question that explicitly states this problem. Maybe someone else comes along who has seen this issue before. Otherwise this will require more debugging effort which is beyond what assistance can be provided over a medium like Stack Overflow.